# Cannot rename folder on Ubuntu from my Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, finder

This is a very old problem, but in Finder I cannot rename a folder on my Ubuntu samba share.  I can create or delete folders, but not add.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a problem with permissions. You have write permissions on directory within you can create files and folders, but if you don't have write permissions on directory you want to delete, it won't allow you.

Important thing about Samba - it works with UID and GID, so you have to have either same UID and GID on both systems for users, or you have to specify under which UID and GID you want to mount the share point.

First thing for troubleshooting - send us result of `ls -al` executed within directory where you can't create files. Otherwise we can guess, not solve.

Regards,

Martin